# CSSBuilder can be used without Griffon?

Tags: css, swing, groovy, griffon

I have a standalone Swing application and I'm using Groovy as programing language.

Trying to  apply styles using CSS and searching for some tool for this purpose, I've found [CSSBuilder](http://griffon.codehaus.org/CSSBuilder).

The problem is that CSSBuilder comes integrated with Griffon framework, so I cannot use all of its features isolated from Griffon, such as 'cssClass' selector.

Therefore my question is simply: has anyone managed to do something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrote a quick test, and this seems to work:

```
@GrabResolver( name='codehaus', root='http://repository.codehaus.org' )
@Grab( 'org.codehaus.griffon:cssbuilder:0.4' )
import griffon.builder.css.*
import groovy.swing.SwingBuilder
import java.awt.BorderLayout as BL

def style = '''* {
  background-color: red;
}

jbutton {
  background-color: blue;
}

.active {
  color: green ;
  font-size: 50%;
}

jlabel {
  color: pink ;
  font-size: 200% ;
}'''

Class klass = javax.swing.JComponent
if( !AbstractSyntheticMetaMethods.hasBeenEnhanced(klass) ) {
   AbstractSyntheticMetaMethods.enhance(klass,[
      "getCssClass": {-> delegate.getClientProperty(ClarityConstants.CLIENT_PROPERTY_CLASS_KEY) },
      "setCssClass": { String cssClass -> delegate.putClientProperty(ClarityConstants.CLIENT_PROPERTY_CLASS_KEY, cssClass) }
   ])
}

new SwingBuilder().edt {
  int count = 0
  def frame = frame( title:'CSS Test', size:[ 300, 300 ], show: true ) {
    borderLayout()
    textlabel = label(text:"Click the button!", constraints: BL.NORTH)
    button(text:'Click Me',
         cssClass: 'active',
         actionPerformed: {count++; textlabel.text = "Clicked ${count} time(s)."; println "clicked"},
         constraints:BL.SOUTH)    
  }
  CSSDecorator.applyStyle( style, frame )
}
```

The meta-class enhancing code I took from the [source of CSSBuilder](https://github.com/griffon/cssbuilder/blob/master/src/main/groovy/griffon/builder/css/CSSBuilder.groovy)